# Convey JSON from controller to AngularJS in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, json

In Laravel, I tried conveying data in MySQL as JSON to AngularJS. Although I  was successful at that, I'm confused how to utilize the values in AngularJS. Any help?

Check output data (hide each value)

[image]

Controller

```
public function index(){
  return Response::json(Company::all());
}
```

AngularJS

```
var app = angular.module('companySearchApp', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});

app.controller('CompanyCtrl', function($scope, $http){
  $http.get('http://localhost:8000/json')
    .then(function(response){
      this.companies = response.data;
    });
});
```

Display

```
<div id="resultTable" align="center">
  <h3>Search Result</h3>

  <div ng-repeat="company in CompanyCtrl.companies">
    <table border="1" style="margin-bottom:10px">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="col-xs-12"><% company.CompanyName %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-4"><% company.City %></td>
        <td class="col-xs-4"><% company.Province %></td>
        <td class="col-xs-4"><% company.KeyWord %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><% company.JobTitle %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><% company.Link %></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, I could fix this by myself. There were 3 steps.

1. JSON path
   Before `$http.get('localhost:8000/json')`
   After `$http.get('/json')`
2. Set JSON to variable
   Before `this.companies = response.data;`
   After `$scope.data = response.data;`
3. ng-repeat
   Before `<div ng-repeat="company in CompanyCtrl.companies">`
   After `<div ng-repeat="company in data">`